# How to navigate through pages of a pageview using RawMaterialButton in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I have three pages(that are three steps a user should take to be authenticated). each page contains a form and a submit RawMaterialButton to get the response back from the server. currently, I am using materialpageroute to navigate between pages. I want to use a vertical pageview that includes all three pages and has a circular indicator and navigate between these three pages with the animation of the pageview, not materialpage route. 
here is one of my pages:

```
class AuthOnePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _AuthOnePageState();
  }
}

class _AuthOnePageState extends State<AuthOnePage> {
  final Map<String, dynamic> _formData = {
    'phone': '',
  };
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Widget _buildPhoneTextField() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.05,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 16,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: CustomColors()),
        color: Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(
          const Radius.circular(40.0),
        ),
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            ' +98',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0 , color: CustomColors().khakestari),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 1.0,
          ),
          VerticalDivider(
            indent: 8.0,
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 4.0),
          Expanded(
            child: TextFormField(
              textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
              textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              autofocus: true,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0 , color: CustomColors().khakestari),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: false,
                isDense: true,
                errorStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0 ,),
                hintText: '',
                hintStyle: TextStyle( fontSize: 22.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
              validator: (String value) {
                if (value.isEmpty ||
                    value.length < 10 ||
                    !RegExp(r"^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$")
                        .hasMatch(value)) {
                  return '';
                }
              },
              onSaved: (String value) {
                _formData['phone'] = value;
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.phone_iphone,
              color: CustomColors(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submitForm(Function authenticateFirst) async {
    if (!_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      return;
    }
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    Map<String, dynamic> successInformation;
    successInformation = await authenticateFirst(_formData['phone']);
    if (successInformation['success']) {
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AuthTwoPage();
      }));
    } else {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text(''),
            content: Text(''),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text(''),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Container(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                      child: Text(
                    '',
                    style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 40.0, fontFamily: 'IrYek'),
                  )),
                  SizedBox(height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7),
                  Form(
                    key: _formKey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        _buildPhoneTextField(),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50.0,
                        ),
                        ScopedModelDescendant<MainModel>(
                          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                              MainModel model) {
                            return model.isLoading
                                ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                                : RawMaterialButton(
                                    highlightElevation: 40,
                                    onPressed: () =>
                                        _submitForm(model.authenticateFirst),
                                    splashColor: Colors.white,
                                    shape: StadiumBorder(),
                                    child: Container(
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                                            colors: <Color>[
                                              Color(0xff4b66ea),
                                              Color(0xff4b66ea),
                                              Color(0xff4b66ea),
                                              Colors.blue
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                              color: Colors.black26,
                                              offset: Offset(0.0, 1.5),
                                              blurRadius: 1.5,
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(40)),
                                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                          1.05,
                                      height:
                                          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /
                                              15,
                                      child: Center(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                              vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                                          child: Text(
                                            '',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontFamily: 'IrBold',
                                                color: Colors.white,
                                                fontSize: 20),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),

    );
  }
```

here is my code for the pageview so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import './authone.dart';
import './authtwo.dart';
import './auththree.dart';



/// An indicator showing the currently selected page of a PageController
class DotsIndicator extends AnimatedWidget {
  DotsIndicator({
    this.controller,
  }) : super(listenable: controller);

  /// The PageController that this DotsIndicator is representing.
  final PageController controller;

  /// The number of items managed by the PageController
  final int itemCount =3 ;

  /// The color of the dots.
  ///
  /// Defaults to `Colors.white`.
  final Color color = Colors.amber[200];

  // The base size of the dots
  static const double _kDotSize = 8.0;

  // The increase in the size of the selected dot
  static const double _kMaxZoom = 2.0;

  // The distance between the center of each dot
  static const double _kDotSpacing = 25.0;

  Widget _buildDot(int index) {
    double selectedness = Curves.easeOut.transform(
      max(
        0.0,
        1.0 - ((controller.page ?? controller.initialPage) - index).abs(),
      ),
    );
    double zoom = 1.0 + (_kMaxZoom - 1.0) * selectedness;
    return new Container(
      width: _kDotSpacing,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Material(
          color: color,
          type: MaterialType.circle,
          child: new Container(
            width: _kDotSize * zoom,
            height: _kDotSize * zoom,
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: new List<Widget>.generate(itemCount, _buildDot),
    );
  }
}

class AuthCollectionPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new AuthCollectionPageState();
}

class AuthCollectionPageState extends State<AuthCollectionPage> {
  final _controller = new PageController(viewportFraction: 0.5);

  static const _kDuration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  static const _kCurve = Curves.ease;

  final _kArrowColor = Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8);

  final List<Widget> _pages = <Widget>[
   AuthOnePage(),
   AuthTwoPage(),
   AuthThreePage()
  ];

  Widget _buildPageItem(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return new Page(page: _pages[index], idx: index);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new IconTheme(
        data: new IconThemeData(color: _kArrowColor),
        child: new Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            new PageView.builder(
              physics: new AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              controller: _controller,
              itemCount: _pages.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _buildPageItem(context, index % _pages.length);
              },
            ),
            new Positioned(
              bottom: 0.0,
              left: 0.0,
              right: 0.0,
              child: new Container(
                color: Colors.grey[800].withOpacity(0.5),
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: new Center(
                  child: new DotsIndicator(
                    controller: _controller,
                    itemCount: _pages.length,
                    onPageSelected: (int page) {
                      _controller.animateToPage(
                        page,
                        duration: _kDuration,
                        curve: _kCurve,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  final page;
  final idx;

  Page({
    @required this.page,
    @required this.idx,
  });

  onTap() {
    print("${this.idx} selected.");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Container(
            height: 200.0,
            child: new Card(
              child: new Stack(
                fit: StackFit.expand,
                children: <Widget>[
                  this.page,
                  new Material(
                    type: MaterialType.transparency,
                    child: new InkWell(onTap: this.onTap),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `"(that are three steps a user should take [...]"` - use [Stepper](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/Stepper-class.html) then

Comment: ok thanks for your answer. but I want to use pageview

Comment: and your problem is...? have you read `PageController` API documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: but honestly i dont understand why you want a `PageView` - `Stepper` docs say: *"A material stepper widget that displays progress through a sequence of steps. Steppers are particularly useful in the case of forms where one step requires the completion of another one, or where multiple steps need to be completed in order to submit the whole form."*

Comment: the sketch of the UI that I have forces me to use the pageview and stepcounter does not fit my need. my problem with page controller is that it gives me this error:

'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_controller.dart': Failed assertion: line 149 pos 12: '_positions.isNotEmpty': ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.

this is my navigate code:

 AuthCollectionPageState().pageController.animateTo(1,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10) , curve: Curves.easeOut );

Comment: you cannot create a state just like that - state is created in `createState` method

Comment: can you explain more please. I am rather new to flutter

Comment: you cannot call `AuthCollectionPageState()` just because you need access to `pageController` - this controller is not attached to anything

Comment: what should I do then?

Comment: this is the code of my authcollectionpagestate class(the part that relates to topic):

class AuthCollectionPageState extends State<AuthCollectionPage> {
  final _controller = new PageController(viewportFraction: 1.0);
  PageController get pageController=>_controller;

Answer (score 0):

The issue here occurs because `PageController _controller` is used on both PageView and DotsIndicator. The code for navigating to a specific page on PageView is correct. You can use the same snippet to be used inside a button.

```dart
_controller.animateToPage(
  page,
  duration: _kDuration,
  curve: _kCurve,
);
```

As for the `DotsIndicator`, set the indicator position using `position` and `dotsCount`.

```dart
DotsIndicator(
  dotsCount: pageLength,
  position: currentIndexPage,
)
```